# Interpretation of AIC plot

Tags: r

```
 best <- regsubsets(log(PrizeMoney)~DrivingAccuracy+GIR+PuttingAverage+BirdieConversion+SandSaves+Scrambling+PuttsPerRound, data = pgatour)

summary(best)

bic <- summary(best)$bic
p <- length(bic)
plot(1:p, bic)
lines(1:p,bic)


aic <- summary(best)$aic
p <- length(aic)
plot(1:p, aic)
lines(1:p,aic)
```

Here is my codes and when I plot aic, I got this below

[image]

I don't know how to interpret this one or is there any problem with my codes?

```
 best <- regsubsets(log(PrizeMoney)~DrivingAccuracy+GIR+PuttingAverage+BirdieConversion+SandSaves+Scrambling+PuttsPerRound, data = pgatour)

summary(best)

bic <- summary(best)$bic
p <- length(bic)
plot(1:p, bic)
lines(1:p,bic)


aic <- summary(best)$aic
p <- length(aic)
plot(1:p, aic)
```

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.